# Specify Room for Lessons

Tags: timefold

I refer to the School-Timetabling use case.

Each lesson now has 3 parameters: subject, teacher and studentGroup.
Rooms are allocated by system.

How do I modify so that each lessons will have 4 parameters: subject, teacher, studentGroup, classRoom?

So timefold will allocate the classroom based on

lessonList.add(new Lesson(nextLessonId++, "Math", "A. Turing", "9th grade","Room A"));

instead of

lessonList.add(new Lesson(nextLessonId++, "Math", "A. Turing", "9th grade"));

Thanks

I am a newbie and interested in time table solutions.
Would like to learn from scratch.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

This demoData was made to allocate a class in the room for you, so you don't have to provide this information to it. Please take a look at the documentation for this part along with an analysis of the Lesson class, you will be able to see that it was created with an @PlanningVariable annotation ( https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/configuration/configuration#planningVariableAnnotation).

https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/quickstart/overview/overview-quickstarts

Comment: Hello, I am from Singapore.
In Singapore, we have a fixed classroom for students instead of teachers.
We also have some additional classroom to be shared by various classes.
We would like to specify classroom to different type of lesson. Eg Science Practical lesson to use Science laboratory. Theory lesson to use their classroom.
Timefold need to ensure that there is no clash in the usage of the science laboratory.
thks

Comment: I'm working on a similar project. In this case, we can work only with the subjects that requires special rooms, assuming that all other classes are already taught in the designated rooms, simplifying the process. You need to model your Lesson class with @PlanningVariable, indicating that time allocation is the responsibility of the timefold. 
For classes that doesn't require a special room, should the timefold decide which teacher teaches which classes?

Comment: Teacher is still assign to class via their subject specialists. Now lesson has the 4th parameters which is the room. If 4th parameters, it use the default classroom.
lessonList.add(new Lesson(nextLessonId++, "Math", "A. Turing", "9th grade","Room A"));

Comment: ok so it's just a normal problem, you don't need to inform the room on the Lesson class, look at the roomList in the same file you are working on (if you are using demoData), there is a roomList variable and you enter the rooms avaibles (in your case, science lab).

obviously you would have to make some changes to the data structure, but it shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: take a look at this, maybe it would help you: https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/responding-to-change/responding-to-change#pinnedPlanningEntities

Comment: The roomList variable, I can understand.
I think I know how to add a room.
Can guide me in modifing the data structure?
How do I 'force' timefold to assign a particular room to a particular lessons?
Thks

Comment: Timefold manages flexible (soft) and strict (hard) constraints. Soft ones, like a student's preference for non-sequential classes, is not a "rule", it may be breakable. Explore the solver folder for built-in timefold constraints. Find details at the link: https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/quickstart/school-timetabling/school-timetabling-constraints#:~:text=Hard%20constraints%20are%20weighted%20against,regardless%20of%20their%20respective%20weights. Contact me via email in my profile if you wish to for a faster response.